# Release the file when application is done using it

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, printing, release

I'm using `WinForms`. In my form I have a button that prints all tif images in a directory. I want to tell my application to release the images if the print job is canceled or if the its done printing. I think that FileInfo is probably the problem here. How can i accomplish this task?

```
    List<string> DocPathList = new List<string>();
    private int page;

    private void btn_Print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DirectoryInfo SourceDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\image\Shared_Directory\Printing_Folder\");
        FileInfo[] Files = SourceDirectory.GetFiles("*.tif"); //Getting Tif files


        foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
        {
            DocPathList.Add(SourceDirectory + file.Name);
        }

        printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
        printPreviewDialog1.Show();
    }

    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image.FromFile(DocPathList[page]), e.MarginBounds);
            page++;
            e.HasMorePages = page < DocPathList.Count;
    }

    private void printDocument1_BeginPrint(object sender, PrintEventArgs e)
    {
        page = 0;
    }
```

If i add this line of code it release the Image. It works if i click on the button once. However, if i want to press the print button the second time `printPreviewDialog1.Show();` throws an error:

> Exception thrown: 'System.ObjectDisposedException' in System.Windows.Forms.dll

```
        using (var image = Image.FromFile(DocPathList[page]))
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, e.MarginBounds);
            page++;
            e.HasMorePages = page < DocPathList.Count;
        }
```

For example, if i cancel my print and then go to file explore to delete/rename/modify this file i the error below.
Currently i have to close my application then i can modify the tif documents.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any case, you'll need to wrap your `image` in a `using` block like you described in your edit, since `Image.FromFile()` will [keep a lock on the file until the image is disposed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5(v=vs.110).aspx).

The `ObjectDisposedException` you're seeing is coming from the `printPreviewDialog`, unrelated to loading images. You can either...

(a) use `printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog(this)` instead to show a dialog modally (i.e., block input to the parent window while the dialog is open), which won't dispose the dialog after closing it

or, (b) use `printPreviewDialog.Show(this)` to show the dialog non-modally, like you do now, but add the following callback:

```
    private void printPreviewDialog1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        // Don't close and dispose the form if the user is just dismissing it. Hide instead.
        if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            printPreviewDialog1.Hide();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to the [EndPrint Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.endprint(v=vs.110).aspx) and delete the file there?

From the documentation:

> EndPrint event also occurs if the printing process is canceled or an
>   exception occurs during the printing process.

Comment: I might not have been clear, I want to just tell the application that i don't want to use these documents anymore, so i don't this windows error: the action cant be completed because the file is open in another application.